# load image into cairo on mono

Tags: c#, image, mono, gtk#, cairo

I looked around for a way to load a png into Cairo using Mono (C#) binding of the library but the closest I got was that in C-binding of the library something like `cairo_image_surface_create_from_png()` was used.  However, in C#-binding of the library I didn't see any useful static members under `Cairo.ImageSurface.*`.  Somewhere an old article mentioned that the binding is incomplete, is this the case?  Currently I'm using `Gdk.Image.Pixbuf` to load in-memory (embedded) images but saw that Gtk+ have moved on to Cairo and that Windows.Forms in Mono are using Cairo, I thought the Cairo's C#-binding would at least be completed enough to include image loading. I'm probably missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I've done this quite recently. You need to load your image into a Cairo Surface:-

```
var icon = new ImageSurface( pngfile );
```

Then you can use the [ImageSurface.Show](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aCairo.Surface.Show%28Cairo.Context,System.Double,System.Double%29) method to render it:

```
icon.Show( ctx, x, y );
```

See more useful things at the [Mono.Cairo Cookbook page](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Cairo_Cookbook).

Comment: Thanks.  I looked at the constructors for ImageSurface class and they seem to offer creating surfaces from byte[] as my png is embedded as a resource (and read off like a stream object).  I'll try it next, but the constructor appear to need width/height which should be in png's metadata, I suspect it may not work like your filesystem based parsing of png.  Other then looping through filesystem, is there another way of getting embedded png into a cairo surface without first parsing it through gdk or the likes? e.g. directly via cairo, or as clean as possible?

Comment: @Bill, not as far as I know. You could probably find the dimensions of the png from the resource stream though.